# C++, fastest way to get milliseconds since midnight

Tags: c++, time

This is code that will run often and have to run fast so I'd like to get some opinions on what the quickest implementation is.  Note, I actually need the full millisecond resolution to some degree of accuracy (so seconds * 1000 does not suffice). For this project, using Boost is OK.

EDIT: The target platform is x64_86 CentOS5, also, hoping to be able to rely on the OS clock so I can also use this in a program that is not running continuously.

Comment: If speed is key, knowing the target platform would be beneficial.

Comment: You are unlikely to get ms resolution on very many platforms.

Comment: Will the program be running continuously so you can keep a start time, or do you have to rely on the OS clock having millisecond accuracy?

Comment: You might want to think about having a thread writing a timestamp every ~500µs to a known place, so that you can at least minimize the number of system calls.

Comment: Sorry for omitting this important information, the platform is 64-bit CentOS.  Also, hoping to rely on the OS clock.  Millisecond should be doable for the OS clock right?

Answer (score 17):

C++ has the chrono library for dealing with time:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

std::chrono::system_clock::duration duration_since_midnight() {
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    time_t tnow = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    tm *date = std::localtime(&tnow);
    date->tm_hour = 0;
    date->tm_min = 0;
    date->tm_sec = 0;
    auto midnight = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(date));

    return now-midnight;
}

int main()
{
    auto since_midnight = duration_since_midnight();

    auto hours = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::hours>(since_midnight);
    auto minutes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(since_midnight - hours);
    auto seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(since_midnight - hours - minutes);
    auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(since_midnight - hours - minutes - seconds);
    auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(since_midnight - hours - minutes - seconds - milliseconds);
    auto nanoseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(since_midnight - hours - minutes - seconds - milliseconds - microseconds);

    std::cout << hours.count() << "h ";
    std::cout << minutes.count() << "m ";
    std::cout << seconds.count() << "s ";
    std::cout << milliseconds.count() << "ms ";
    std::cout << microseconds.count() << "us ";
    std::cout << nanoseconds.count() << "ns\n";
}
```

It depends on your implementation what exactly the resolution you get is. VS 11 beta claims the resolution to be 100ns, although I can't say how accurate it is.

```
11h 51m 57s 285ms 699us 600ns
```

Comment: this doesn't look very fast, you're finding two times to get the difference.

Comment: I'm finding what two times to get the difference? This accesses the clock once, then does some conversions between time_t, tm, and system_clock::time_point. I'm not sure how long those conversions take. One way to improve performance though would be to simply use the clock's native epoch rather than insist on using the time since midnight; You could simply use system_clock::time_point directly, or do the conversions at a later time.

Comment: @Barnes53 your solution is exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Does this compile in standard C++?  I'm getting: error: chrono: No such file or directory

Comment: @user788171 The `<chrono>` library was added in C++11. This works in VS 2011, gcc at least [as far back as 4.5](http://ideone.com/vBt6D), clang with libc++.

Comment: Ah, I'm stuck with the standard g++ 4.1.2 with CentOS5 (other code built with this, all Boost libraries compiled with 4.1.2). Is there a workaround to get this to work, is it included in Boost?

Comment: @user788171 Yes, it is in Boost ([1.47](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono.html)) as well! `#include <boost/chrono/chrono.hpp>` and the namespace is `boost::chrono` instead of `std::chrono`. And the boost version doesn't need the `.count()` to print durations. Also you can't use `auto` without C++11 so you'll have to write out the full types.

Comment: It looks like it is only available in Boost 1.47 and later, unfortunately, for this project, Boost 1.45 is used and there's no plan yet to migrate to a later version of Boost.

Comment: @user788171 perhaps you could look at the boost implementation and steal it directly.

Answer (score 1):

There's an article from Microsoft ["Implement a Continuously Updating, High-Resolution Time Provider for Windows"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx) detailing how to use `QueryPerformanceCounter` to get high resolution times.

Comment: But unfortunately it isn't guaranteed to work on all systems.
I have seen systems where GetPerformanceFrequency returns 0.  Looking at the link, this isn't taken into account.

Comment: Unfortunately, not using Windows so this won't work for me.

Comment: @user788171, too bad. I know that the QueryPerformanceCounter function is based on some extensions to the x86 instruction set that would be available on another OS but I'm not sure how to utilize it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Good article, nice read for those not on a posix os,And system details are important for figuring out which approach to make.

Answer (score -7):

I would try creating a timer to check time each second for example. If time until midnight is less then K seconds:

```
while(True)
{
    if (checkTime() >= MIDNIGHT))
    {
        break; 
    }
}
```