# Casting time_points between std::chrono clocks

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

The title line of this post is really only one half (the simpler half) of my question. So, I'll step back a moment to talk about what I'm trying to do.

It's pretty easy to measure elapsed time with `std::chrono`. However, I haven't seen any "Timer" implementations thus far that would do the equivalent of laps on a stopwatch. That is to say, you call `Timer.start()` when you want to start tracking intervals, and call `Timer.tick()` every time you want to record an interval. Then, after the fast stuff is over, you could look back on the list of time intervals recorded; maybe account for averages and 1% highs or something.

Also, because I use it a lot, I'd want to arbitrarily ask the timer how many microseconds have elapsed since midnight.

The first task for a constructor for this imaginary class would be to set midnight internally. Initially, I was doing this via the technique from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11123391/1464937) wonderful answer. As I went to implement my notion of a `Timer` class, though, I realized I wanted to use either `high_resolution_clock` or `steady_clock` (even though `system_clock` uses nanosecond intervals on my platform). The issue then arises: how to set a `chrono::steady_clock::time_point` to midnight?

Only `system_clock` has `to_time_t` and `from_time_t`, and in so far as I can tell, that's the only way to express "today at midnight" in a way that `chrono` understands. And for all my reading last night, I couldn't find a way to cast a `system_clock::time_point` to a `steady_clock::time_point`. My nearest attempt was:

```
typedef std::conditional<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::is_steady,
                         std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
                         std::chrono::steady_clock>::type TimerClock;

TimerClock::time_point midnight;

chrono::system_clock::time_point current_time = chrono::system_clock::now();

time_t raw_time = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(current_time);

tm *tm_midnight = localtime(&raw_time);
tm_midnight->tm_hour = 0;
tm_midnight->tm_min  = 0;
tm_midnight->tm_sec  = 0;

midnight = chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(mktime(tm_midnight));
```

But obviously that won't fly. And in so far as I can tell, `chrono::time_point_cast` is designed to give you access to different resolutions from the same clock type.

This leaves me with two routes/questions:

- Can I directly set the value of a `time_point` from `high_precision_clock` or `steady_clock` to be "today at midnight"
- Can I convert a `system_clock::time_point` to be used with a different `chrono` clock?

And, of course, I'd be happy to be pointed to a better method of dealing with this all together, if it still lines up with my overall goals above.

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: One complication is that system_clock is likely to jump an hour twice a year (DST). The steady_clock is not.

Comment: Ah yes. For my purposes, this Timer will never run for more than a few hours.

Comment: I sometimes capture a time point when my program starts.  Any subsequent time-points can compute a duration-since-begin-of-program.  Would this be reasonable?  I am sure the startup time point can captured with the 'wall clock' time.  And I think it would be simple modular arithmetic to adjust all lap times to ms-since-midnight.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the simpler approach. If I was content to let it just be a stopwatch, then that's what I would do. But I want to be able to ask it for seconds since midnight arbitrarily, too. Namely for timestamping log messages. The duration of each tick will always be on the same clock, so this question is really just for having a `us_since_midnight()` member function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate midnight on the system clock.

Get a time point for both the system clock, and the clock you want midnight on, at "the same time" (approx).  Call this time point X.

Convert the interval from midnight to X on system clock.  Convert to a duration in picoseconds (or whatever resolution).

You now have the time since midnight in picoseconds for time point X on the clock you want midnight on.

Note that this is going to be fundamentally approximate, because the "time X" is going to be a line apart for system clock and the clock you care about.  But it will only differ by about the time it takes to calculate a time stamp.  If you really care, you can do two system clock samples braketing the target clock and average the time since midnight.